# Galleria video not showing video icon in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, responsive, galleria

In my drupal commerce website we are using Galleria for product slideshow.
According to recent requirement we needed **a (youtube) video to be added as the second item in the slideshow**.
I achieved that by using `splice function` as mentioned [here](https://docs.galleria.io/article/128-manipulation):

```
(function($){
  Galleria.ready(function(options) {  

    var gallery = this;
    gallery.splice(1, 0, { video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wNzzCWWEdg' });
      });

})(jQuery);
```

As shown below, this is working totally fine in **laptop/desktop**.

[image]

In **mobile phones**, the video is getting added properly in second position, **but it has two issues.**

1. The **video icon** at the center of image **is missing**.
2. User has to click twice to play the video. When clicked, first it
       loads the *actual youtube video* and then user has to click again to
       play the video.

*What I have checked so far to fix the issue :*

a. Through "Inspect Element", I found that there is this element which is being appended in DOM in desktop **but not in DOM in mobile**.

```
<div class="galleria-videoicon">
  <i></i>
</div>
```

b. In console, following error(`TypeError: img is undefined`) shows for mobile devices.

[image]

I tried looking into the galleria.js file at line number 3069 as shown in error. I could not figure out much here.

[image]

How do I take next step to solve it? 
Any tips/guidance much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

I have also tried adding **Video icon** to gallery elements explicitly for mobile devices.

```
   //For Mobile Devices
    Galleria.on('image', function(e) {
          $(e.imageTarget).after("DOM_FOR_ICON");            
    });
```

But this(Or any other JS code) does not work for first two elements on Gallery. It works only on third and further elements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you showed, it looks to me that the code on line `3062` is doing a silent fail to `undefined`

On line `3064`, try adding these lines:

```
console.log(img);
console.log(self);
console.log(self._controls);
console.log(self._controls.slides);
console.log(self._controls.slides[loadme])
```

Or if you have a debugger on your editor/IDE, it would be better to add a debugging breakpoint on line `3064` instead

What does that gives you in the console? If you get anything `undefined` here, that could be the culprit. You can go backward up the stack from there to pinpoint it further with more precision...